# Communicating with a docker using Unix domain sockets

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm trying to communicate with Nginx docker from docker hub without using network stack (unix sockets only)

I tried to create my own socket:
`python -c "import socket as s; sock = s.socket(s.AF_UNIX); sock.bind('/tmp/nginx.sock')"`

and run the docker with `-v /tmp/nginx.sock:/tmp/nginx.sock`

> Got:curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server

I also tried binding the dockerd socket but I think it's not the best thing to do.

Comment: If you use `ls -l`, is that path actually a socket, on either the host or container side?  Or is it an empty directory?

Comment: the python command creates the socket in this path

Comment: Why would the nginx container talk to the socket `/tmp/nginx.sock` that you mount into the container?

Comment: when using curl after the socket you should specify a url, I used http://localhost which is port 80 and docker is listening on port 80, when this didn't work I changed nginx config to listen on this unix socket instead port 80 but this didn't work as well. how would you suggest to achive the requested behavior?

Comment: Correction : *nginx in the docker ia listening on port 80

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create this socket by nginx daemon? Try to mount a specific folder and leave the socket file creation to nginx daemon.

Comment: when running "docker ... -v /tmp/nginx.sock:/tmp/nginx.sock" it just creates a folder nginx.sock